# Installshield Chained MSI not executing repair for individual MSI

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have 3 MSI inside a chained msi Basic MSI Project.

Install and Uninstall are working properly but if i choose repair, InstallShield only executes the parent MSI and ignore all other MSI inside it.

I have followed the instructions from
http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?191832-Repair-chained-msi

and set ecoReinstallInstalled on the options column, but it doesnt seems to work

Any idea what am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

So you have a wrapper or parent MSI spawning the 3 chained MSIs?  You will need to pass REINSTALL=ALL to each of the chained MSIs via the install property.  But only if each of the MSIs have already been installed, so maybe a custom action to detect a first time install or not and then setting a property or properties with REINSTALL=ALL.

http://installdeploy.com/blog/

Comment: I did that and it didn't work. We decided to get away with the chained MSI in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the flag called ecoReinstallInstalled (Installshield help does not mentioned this keyword) which is referred to in the document titled “Using Chained MSI Packages to Componentize Your Windows Installer Setup”.

Basically, you change the ‘option’ column of the ISChainPackage table of the specified chained MSI by adding the value 16 to the current value. If the value is less than 16; for example, the value is 0, replace it with 16; if the value is 1, replace it with 17 and so on. The option value determines the UI Level mode (the mode in which the chained MSI will run); 0 for Basic UI, 1 for No UI, value 16 or above will allow the chained MSI to re-run after it has been already installed.

If this does not work, which it should you need to check the chained MSI's log file by modifying the property IS_CHAINER_POST_COMMANDLINE, you could also try running the chained MSI in ui mode to see what the behaviour is.

Interestingly what alternative did you use instead of the Chained MSI functionality?

Look at my blog which by the way web page is work in progress:

http://installdeploy.com/wordpress/blog/